# Turing machine - Check if $a^p$ is prime

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Question: Check if number of $a$ are prime with **just two tapes** in Tuning machine.

I'm not quite sure how to check it but what I've got so far is:

**First tape will be the input**. For example $aaaaa$

**Second tape will be checking the numbers** $2$ till $n-1$, meaning $4$ for this example.

We start checking them both from the beginning of the tapes, we write '$aa$' in the second tape, **making some checks which I'm not sure**, if we fail with these checks, start again but now with '$aaa$', and then lastly '$aaaa$'.

Comment: You can even do it with one tape. Check whether there exists $1 < i < p$ that divides $p$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If I put for example the number 2 in the second tape, and I want to check it with the number 5 with the first tape, how is it possible from that point to check for division? Let's assume we counted 5 in the first tape, and 2 in the second tape, and now the 'head' is at the end of the first and second tape. How can I continue from here to check for arithmatic things. Btw, much appreciation for your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Use your imagination. The number $i$ divides $p$ if we can concatenate several copies of $a^i$ to eventually reach $a^p$.

Comment: I'm not sure yet how to do that. What I thought of up till now is to convert to binary both numbers and to work from there. Check if the last digit is $0$ already meaning it's not divisible by $2$, which eliminates many possibilities. When you say concatenate several copies of $a^i$ we can add $i$ to itself until we're bigger or equal of $p$. if we find once we're equal, we end it. But I guess I'm going back to the tutorials to read the fundamentals again, I'm not quite familiar with what we can assume when answering those questions. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Lets suppose we have a tape
       
    Blank|1|1|1|1|1|Blank

Now we have to check whether this number 5 is prime or not by designing a turing machine. 

What I've done so far is that, we will check by making pairs, For example,

First we divide by 2, 2 = 11.11.1 = Not divisible by 2

Then divide by 3, 3 = 111.11 = Not divisible by 3

Then divide by 4, 4 = 1111.1 = Not divisible by 4

Then divide by 5, 5 = 11111 = divisible by 5(Prime). @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Converting to binary seems like a bad idea, since it will make everything more complicated. An approach like in your last comment seems the simplest option.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well, you can do anything with a one-tape Turing machine, if you can do it at all, so I'm not sure that part of your comment is really helpful. Having two tapes is much easier, since you don't need to spend your entire life scanning back and forth and putting marker characters down to remind yourself where you used to be.

Comment: Right, the two parts were supposed to be completely separate, but do not look that way. You can do it with one tape if you can do it at all, just as you say.